# In how many days the Firebase Storage quota reset in free plan

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am on Firebase Spark plan and I got this error message in my Logcat today.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 402,    "message": "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more.",    "status": "ACCESS_BUCKET"  }}

I just want to know if this will renew or I have to upgrade my plan.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing):

> Firebase Storage free limits are enforced daily and refreshed at midnight Pacific Time.

Comment: Why in the world the limits won't reset according to selected server's location or simply Google account location? Right now is situation where the time shift for me is 7 hours.